# How to make input box a certain length?

Tags: html, css, alignment

So I have this HTML/CSS,

```css
input {
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 35px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
  margin-right: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p><label for="mobTag"><strong>Mob Tag</strong> = <input type="text" id="mobTag" placeholder="My Mob" name="mobTag"></label></p>

<p><label for="chestName"><strong>Chest Name</strong> = <input type="text" id="chestName" placeholder="empty" name="chestName"></label></p>
```

and as you can see, the labels are nicely aligned, but I'm trying to get the end of the `input`s to align as well. I tried increasing the `width`, hoping the `margin-right` would hide the overflow, but it just pushes the labels up a line.
Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to put them inside div's.

Comment: Just float them to the right.

Comment: @MrLister but then they don't start directly after the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex`:

```css
p {width:50%; margin:1rem auto}

input {
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 35px;
  border: none;
  margin-left:.5rem;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240);
  flex:1 0;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin: 30px;
}

strong {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right:.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p><label for="mobTag"><strong>Mob Tag</strong> = <input type="text" id="mobTag" placeholder="My Mob" name="mobTag"></label></p>

<p><label for="chestName"><strong>Chest Name</strong> = <input type="text" id="chestName" placeholder="empty" name="chestName"></label></p>
```

Comment: That works, but it also gets rid of the spaces around the equals signs. Is there anyway to keep them?